# Opening a URL from a JButton in simple Java Program?

Tags: java, swing, hyperlink, awt, jbutton

Hello there community :),
So I'm a real java newb, right? I can't seem to get a URL to open from my LINK GUI. At the moment, it just shows the fields value.

Here is my handler.java code:

```
google = new JButton("Google");
google.setToolTipText("Open Google");
add(google);
```

I want it to open a URL instead of showing the fields value. This is my actionlistener code:

```
    private class HandlerClass implements ActionListener {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, String.format("%s", event.getActionCommand()));

    }

}
```

If this is possible, can I get some assistance? :) Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [`Desktop.browse(URI)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#browse%28java.net.URI%29).

> I get an error, `Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method browse(URI) from the type Desktop`

No, that is what will happen when you attempt to call an instance method on a class.  You need a `Desktop` object.

```
URI uri = new URI("http://google.com/");
Desktop dt = Desktop.getDesktop();
dt.browse(uri.toURL());
```

Comment: `URI url = new URI("http://google.com/");
Desktop.browse(url);`

I get an error,
`Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method browse(URI) from the type Desktop`

Comment: Retreive the system's desktop object: `public static Desktop getDesktop()` Please read the API linked in the answer.

Comment: @Andrew Thompson, I used your snippet, but now it says this error:
`The method browse(URI) in the type Desktop is not applicable for the arguments (URL)`

Comment: @AndrewThompson This was back when I didn't know the etiquette of SO. I've accepted your answer after all this time. :)

Answer (score 2):

This may be of use to others. Andrew Thompson's answer is almost there.

```
try {

     String url ="http://www.stackoverflow.com";

     Desktop dt = Desktop.getDesktop();
     URI uri = new URI(url);
     dt.browse(uri.resolve(uri));


 } catch (URISyntaxException ex) {
     Logger.getLogger(Setting.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
 } catch (IOException ex) {
     Logger.getLogger(Setting.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
 }
```

The code above needs to be surrounded with a try catch block, that includes both a URISyntaxException and an IOException.